# CSS, div layouting?

Tags: css

I have a parent container div and 2 sub ones in it, one to the left of the parent and one in the horizontal middle. how can I do that using css? suppose the html code is like this:

```
<div id="ParentContainer">
  <div id="SubContainerToLeft"></div>
  <div id="SubContainerInHorMiddle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Sorry for being rookie! I`ve tried but didnot use float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
#ParentContainer {
     height: 100px;
     width: 500px;
}

#SubContainerToLeft {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
}

#SubContainerInHorMiddel {
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
}
```

And then just play with margin and padding as much as you like. You know what margin and padding is, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: :)

http://jsfiddle.net/bzUSY/